# Iterating an AX 4 Container getting out of range error

Tags: c#, axapta

I am trying to iterate an AX container using the BuisnessConnector. However I get an index out of range exception on the below code, even though the container returns a count of 4. This happens on the first iteration of the loop.

```
            AxaptaContainer path = (AxaptaContainer)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("DocumentHandling", "ItemData", "1000000");
            for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
            {
                string somestring = path.get_Item(i).ToString();
            }
```

I am using AX 4 for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the container starts at 1.

So: `for (int i = 1; i <= path.Count; i++)`

Or is this too obvious?